# Java Nested try catch block unreachable issues

Tags: java, try-catch

Here is part of my code...when i want to compile it 
 it always shows Unreachable catch block for SelfDefineException.
 This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

how can i fix it, could anyone can help me, cuz i have tried million times to solve it

```
    try
    {
        Statement 1;
        Statement 1;
        Statement 1;
        Statement 1;

        try
        {
           Statement 3;
        }
        catch (SelfDefineException er)
        {
            String error = er.getMessage();

            System.out.print("issue: \n\t(" +er.getMessage() + ")");
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SelfDefineException er)
    {
        System.out.print("failed: " + er.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: which `catch` block? you have 2.

Comment: Look at your curly brackets. I believe they are not properly matched.

Comment: you have 2 curly braces after 1st catch...

Comment: (Because of school policy, i cannot show all the code) all of these two catch block show  Unreachable catch block for SelfDefineException.  About the brackets it was my typing mistake,skip them..

Answer (score 1):

If SelfDefineException is a checked exception (which it probably is, unless it is extending RuntimeException), you should catch it or declare it (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html). There are three possible scenarios that may give an "unreachable code" here:

1. If Statement 3 is the only one that calls a method that throws SelfDefineException, the second catch is unreachable, as the statements above can't throw that.
2. If Statement 3 doesn't contain a call to a method that throws SelfDefineException, the first catch is unreachable.
3. If none contain calls to methods that declare "throws SelfDefineException" in its method definition, both catch blocks are unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The curly bracket should yield a parse error, not an unreachable statement error.

What's probably happening is that in one of the try blocks there isn't anything throwing the exception in the first place.

Also, why use

```
System.out.print("issue: \n\t(" +er.getMessage() + ")");
```

when you already have a variable declared containing `er.getMessage()` in the line before?

You should just use the variable, it will at least make the code more a tiny bit more readable.

```
System.out.print("issue: \n\t(" + error + ")");
```